# Override SetText for different types of buttons

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Hey guys i have an implementation doubt.

Im use different types of buttons, `Android.Widget.Button`, `Google.Android.Material.Button`, `Android.Widget.CompoundButton`, etc and i need to have a way to perform some text validations before displaying the text itself.

Right now i have different custom views that extend the different types of buttons that i use but this doesnt seem the best way to do it. Isnt there a easier way to do it? Like having some sort of generic Button that can handle all of these different cases?

```
public CustomButton : Button
{
//Constructors

override SetText....
}

public CustomButton2 : MaterialButton
{
//Constructors

override SetText....
}
```

Comment: What you are doing is probably as easy as it gets. See if you can write one `static` helper method that you pass parameters to, so that your overrides only need a single line of code, to call that helper with desired parameters. the `static` can be in one of those classes, or in any convenient class that all your custom buttons can refer to.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve yeah, thats exactly what i did

Comment: Could you provide some code related to `.xaml`?